# Mongoose, Node.js how to increment a specific value of all records in a collection by a value specified in the record itself?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry if the title is unclear, i'll make it a bit clearer now.

I have several records in a collection, the records are called users and each user has variable called "x" which is to be incremented every hour. To increment x by a constant every hour would be easy, I used this:

```
User.update({},{$inc:{"x":1}},{},()=>{
   console.log("success")
})
```

my problem is, i introduced a variable called "xIncrement" which is unique to every user. how would i go about increasing the x value of each user by their unique "xIncrement" value every hour?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but still:

```
//run this every hour
User.find({}, function (err, doc) {    
    for (var i=0; i<doc.length; i++) {            
        User.update({xIncrement:doc[i].xIncrement},$inc:{x:doc[i].xIncrement}, function (err, doc){
              //code
        });      
     }  
});
```

Comment: thanks, but shouldn't the User.update have a query parameter?

Comment: is it possible to get a solution without a for loop going through the entire collection? i'm worried about the effects that might have on performance

Comment: Dont know about database query but in js you could just pre create a map with `key as _id` and `value as xIncrement` then you will have to just use `User.findByIdandUpdate()` map.size times. This will surely better the performance as you will not have to call `User.findall` every hour.